# Replacing a line in a file with another line using sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Here is what I am trying to get working:

I have the following line in a configuration file

```
subscribed_pages[]=WikiPage.ChildPage.*
```

I want to walk a bunch of files and replace that line that starts with `subscribed_pages[]=` and no matter what the rest of the line is I want it to look like.

```
subscribed_pages[]=*
```

I am trying to do this with one file and getting the following error.

```
sed 's/subscribed_pages[]=.*/subscribed_pages[]=\*/' -i  1288079906.93.57631
sed: -e expression #1, char 46: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape your `[` and `]` as `\[` and `\]` in your search pattern.

```
$ echo 'subscribed_pages[]=WikiPage.ChildPage.*' \
    | sed -e 's/subscribed_pages\[\]=.*/subscribed_pages[]=\*/'
subscribed_pages[]=*
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides escaping your brackets, you can avoid typing again the match in the replacement part:

```
sed -r 's/(subscribed_pages\[\]=).*/\1\*/'
```

\1 to \9 refer to the nth parenthetized string (a "group" in regex speak)